# Find number of null records between two non-null records in scala dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-window-function

I have a dataframe as shown below.

```
|  ID | date       | sig01_diff |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 123 | 2019-11-04 | 93668      |
| 123 | 2019-11-05 | 49350      |
| 123 | 2019-11-07 | null       |
| 123 | 2019-11-08 | 11069      |
| 123 | 2019-11-09 | 33203      |
| 123 | 2019-11-11 | 47927      |
| 123 | 2020-01-21 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-01-22 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-01-23 | 33908      |
| 123 | 2020-01-24 | 61603      |
| 123 | 2020-01-27 | 33613      |
| 123 | 2020-01-28 | 27514      |
| 123 | 2020-01-29 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-01-30 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-02-11 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-02-12 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-02-13 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-02-14 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-02-15 | 65625      |
| 123 | 2020-02-17 | 13354      |
| 123 | 2020-02-18 | null       |
| 123 | 2020-02-19 | 69069      |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

I have to get number of null record preceding to a record as shown below.

```
|  ID | date       | sig01_diff |null_count |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------+
| 123 | 2019-11-04 | 93668      | 00        |
| 123 | 2019-11-05 | 49350      | 00        |
| 123 | 2019-11-07 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2019-11-08 | 11069      | 01        |
| 123 | 2019-11-09 | 33203      | 00        |
| 123 | 2019-11-11 | 47927      | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-01-21 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-01-22 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-01-23 | 33908      | 02        |
| 123 | 2020-01-24 | 61603      | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-01-27 | 33613      | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-01-28 | 27514      | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-01-29 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-01-30 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-02-11 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-02-12 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-02-13 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-02-14 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-02-15 | 65625      | 06        |
| 123 | 2020-02-17 | 13354      | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-02-18 | null       | 00        |
| 123 | 2020-02-19 | 69069      | 01        |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------+
```

As shown above the new column will have a count of null records preceding to that record.
for example for below dates:

```
2019-11-08
2020-02-15
```

Using window function and unboundpreceding, I am able to find count of null records incrementally within a window. But my requirement is within a window the count of null records between two non-null records.

[image]

How could I achieve this ? Any leads appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are no direct functions to find out number of null records between two non-null records.

Below provided a working solution for this question.

```
%scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val dfTest = Seq(
    (1,1,10,1),
    (1,2,10,2),
    (1,3,0,1),
    (1,4,20,1),
    (1,5,0,1),
    (1,6,0,1),
    (1,7,60,0),
    (1,8,0,2),
    (1,9,0,1),
    (1,10,0,1),
    (1,11,80,1),
    (1,7,60,1),
    (2,1,10,1),
    (2,2,10,2),
    (2,3,0,1),
    (2,4,20,0),
    (2,5,0,0),
    (2,6,0,1),
    (2,7,60,1)
  ).toDF("ID","date","A","B")

val test = dfTest.withColumn("A", when((col("A") === 0),null).otherwise(col("A")))
  .withColumn("B", when((col("B") === 0),null).otherwise(col("B")))
```

The Input dataframe is as shown below.

```
+---+----+----+----+
| ID|date|   A|   B|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|   1|  10|   1|
|  1|   2|  10|   2|
|  1|   3|null|   1|
|  1|   4|  20|   1|
|  1|   5|null|   1|
|  1|   6|null|   1|
|  1|   7|  60|null|
|  1|   8|null|   2|
|  1|   9|null|   1|
|  1|  10|null|   1|
|  1|  11|  80|   1|
|  1|   7|  60|   1|
|  2|   1|  10|   1|
|  2|   2|  10|   2|
|  2|   3|null|   1|
|  2|   4|  20|null|
|  2|   5|null|null|
|  2|   6|null|   1|
|  2|   7|  60|   1|
+---+----+----+----+
```

The solution is provided as below.

```
val w2 = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("date")
val w3 = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow-1)


val newDf = test
  .withColumn("A_cnt", count(when(col("A").isNull, 1)).over(w3))
  .withColumn("B_cnt", count(when(col("B").isNull, 1)).over(w3))
  .withColumn("A_null", when(col("A").isNotNull && lag(col("A"),1).over(w2).isNull, col("A_cnt")).otherwise(null))
  .withColumn("B_null", when(col("B").isNotNull && lag(col("B"),1).over(w2).isNull, col("B_cnt")).otherwise(null))
  .withColumn("A_null_cnt", when(col("A").isNotNull && lag(col("A"),1).over(w2).isNull, col("A_null") - last("A_null", true).over(w3)).otherwise(null))
  .withColumn("B_null_cnt", when(col("B").isNotNull && lag(col("B"),1).over(w2).isNull, col("B_null") - last("B_null", true).over(w3)).otherwise(null))
  .drop("A_cnt")
  .drop("B_cnt")
  .drop("A_null")
  .drop("B_null")
```

And the output will be as shown below.

```
+---+----+----+----+------------+------------+
| ID|date|   A|   B|  A_null_cnt|  B_null_cnt|
+---+----+----+----+------------+------------+
|  1|   1|  10|   1|        null|        null|
|  1|   2|  10|   2|        null|        null|
|  1|   3|null|   1|        null|        null|
|  1|   4|  20|   1|           1|        null|
|  1|   5|null|   1|        null|        null|
|  1|   6|null|   1|        null|        null|
|  1|   7|  60|null|           2|        null|
|  1|   7|  60|   1|        null|           1|
|  1|   8|null|   2|        null|        null|
|  1|   9|null|   1|        null|        null|
|  1|  10|null|   1|        null|        null|
|  1|  11|  80|   1|           3|        null|
|  2|   1|  10|   1|        null|        null|
|  2|   2|  10|   2|        null|        null|
|  2|   3|null|   1|        null|        null|
|  2|   4|  20|null|           1|        null|
|  2|   5|null|null|        null|        null|
|  2|   6|null|   1|        null|           2|
|  2|   7|  60|   1|           2|        null|
+---+----+----+----+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use window function with `rowsBetween` defined with `Window.currentRow - 1` as the upper bound. Here is an example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{count, when, col}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

val df = List((1, Some(1)), (2, None), (3, Some(3)), (4, None), (5, Some(4))).toDF("id", "nullable_value")

val w = Window
  .orderBy(col("id"))
  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow - 1)

df.withColumn("not_null_count", count(when(col("nullable_value").isNull, 1)).over(w)).show()

+---+--------------+--------------+
| id|nullable_value|not_null_count|
+---+--------------+--------------+
|  1|             1|             0|
|  2|          null|             0|
|  3|             3|             1|
|  4|          null|             1|
|  5|             4|             2|
+---+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The requirement is little bit different from the solution. Is it possible to get the count of null values between that row and previous non null record?

Comment: I have added an image at the end of question to show the difference between provided answer and requirement. Please have a look. @Gabio